# Uiautomator for android TV

Tags: android, python, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm using Uiautomator tool in python for android phone.
But , now I'm interested using it on android TV.

I did the setup for android tv same as that of android phone.
But I found that message_app.click()will not work in TV.

Below is my code snippet

```
from uiautomator import Device
d = Device('SerialNumberOfDevice')
message_app =  d(className=”android.widget.TextView”, description=”Messaging”) #initialize message app
message_app.click()
```

I suspect that , this is because click() was implemented as "touch events" .
But , In TV we will not use "touch events " instead we use Remote controller.

Is there any way to implement click() for android TV.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On Android TV, users primarily use the DPad to navigate and click on elements.

You can use [UiDevice.pressDPadDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#pressDPadDown()) (or up, left, right, etc) to change focus and [UiDevice.pressDPadCenter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#pressDPadCenter()) to "click".